# How can I specify the width and height of the Featured Image in TwentyTwelve theme?

Tags: post-thumbnails, featured-post, customization

I am trying to get set the width, height and position of the Featured image for a new page I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the height and width of `the_post_thumbnail` use the following:

`the_post_thumbnail( array(height,width))`

Where it would show in code like this:

`if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
                                            the_post_thumbnail( array(200,999))`

[More Info on Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)